# Slam 2.4.1 doesn't open on Linux Debian 7

Tags: linux, slamdata

I install Slam 2.4.1 on Debian 7 with java 8
Running

```
./SlamData I see 
Server started listening on port 20223
Press Enter to stop.
```

and on log I got

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Failed to open browser, please navigate to http://localhost:20223/
```

Opening http://<serverIP>:20223/ the browser still loads page till I get a timeout

opening a telnet on <serverIP> 20223 I got

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 15 Feb 2016 15:11:15 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have success if you use a browser to open `http://localhost:20223/slamdata/index.html`, instead.